# How to open excel in robotframework in selenium?

Tags: robotframework

I have been trying to open excel sheet using robotframework, below is the code i tried:

```
*** Settings ***
    Library           Selenium2Library
    Library           ExcelLibrary

*** Variables ***
    ${path_excel}   D:\\Users\\thejav\\Desktop\\pydev.xlsx

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open Excel     ${path_excel}
```

But, I am getting this error:

> FAIL : NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented

Answer (score 0):

I think Excel Library does not yet support .xlsx type of Excel files. Hence you are getting this error. You will need to convert your .xlsx file to .xls file and then use.

[Keyword documentation](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html#Open%20Excel)

Answer (score 0):

For xlsx, you can use openpyxl library.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Your .xlsx file to .xls , same code will work.

To Convert:
open exxcel-> click on save as-> change extension to excel 97-2003 workbook